# What's wrong with the i7 6700k and asus z170 pro gaming?

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, computer-building

Hi i'm recently building a new rig. Since my old pc died after 7 years. So i thought, my time as come.
Here's my build

- CPU - i7 6700k
- mobo: asus z170 pro gaming
- RAM: g skill 2x8gb @3000 mhz (checked the board manuel, it does support my ram)
  SSD : 240GB
- GPU: Gtx 970 4g
- CPU cooler: CM nepton 240m
- PSU: CM G750M.

Now, while i tried to boot up my pc after i put everything in their place. Everything in the case runs just fine, lights are up, fans are spinning. I also tried to search up everything i could and tried all the solutions on the internet (ex. other rams sticks/slots, boot up without GPU, etc.) Clear CMOS, shortened the pins..)
After all of that i still got the same result, my PC won't boot, not even post to bios. This is very frustating cause this has caused me a lot of money. I had worked very hard for it.. ( feels me? )
Lots of people seem to have the same problem, does any of them fixed this issue cause i haven't seen any topic with this problem got solved so..
I also think that MOBO is fine cause i just got a new one after i bent the old one's pin. Maybe the I7 6700K itself?

Comment: Have you checked all connections? I recently build a PC and the CPU power connector was loose, so the CPU did not work (but the rest did).

Comment: Yes, i double checked every wires. anything was well plugged.

Comment: What do you mean your old motherboard had a bent pin, it was 7 years old, why does an incompatible motherboard have to do with anything?

Comment: I meant the new build i'm building, the first mobo i ordered i accidently bent the socket pin so i needed to order a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible the fan is not properly secured with cooling paste. Basically the system turns on but no video, as the system protects from overheating.

I solved this problem once by simply removing and reseating the cooler.